# PickMeUp date picker - removed default current date

Tags: jquery

I'm using PickMeUp multi date picker and this is my jquery code.

```
$('.multiple').pickmeup({
        position        : 'top',
        hide_on_select  : false,
        mode    : 'multiple'
});
```

The calendar always have default date selected when calendar showup which is the current date. Please any help to remove default date selection on the calendar. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `default_date: false`

See here: https://github.com/nazar-pc/PickMeUp#user-content-configuration-options

> Allows to keep empty value until date selected, but open PickMeUp at this default date (false for no default date)

### Update

Here's a workaround that will remove the `selected` class entirely, along with the highlighting of today's date:

```
before_show: function() {
    $(".pmu-today").removeClass("pmu-selected pmu-today");
}
```

Example: http://jsbin.com/kavusibomu/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Hello. I've tried your suggestion and still same issue.

Comment: Then you have an issue somewhere else. It works perfectly in this demo: http://jsbin.com/linicuzafa/edit?html,js,output (click "Run with JS")

Comment: Sorry but that demo still same issue as mine. Do you think it is a browser issue or something? Thank you.

Comment: There is no selected date on the calendar. Do you mean how it _highlights_ today's date? It's highlighting, it's not selecting. You can tell by selecting a different date, and notice that today is still highlighted.

Comment: Yes it highlights today date and still highlighted when selecting different date. What I'm doing right now is click first the today date to remove highlight then select different date. Because If did not do this, today date and date which I selected will be loaded to input box. I wan't to remove the highlight of today's date on calendar show up.

Comment: @Eric see my updated answer. this workaround seems to do exactly what you want.

Comment: Thank you for time jszobody. Now the date today is not highlighted on calendar show up. But when I select different date, today date will be highlighted automatically and loaded also in input box